# How get Google Analytics report of selected pages using an regex?

Tags: google-analytics, regex

We want to make a report of visitors of a selected set of pages.

So we use "Behavior" > "Site Content" > "All Pages".

We fill in part of the pagenames, so `FR_PLT*` for pages `FR_PLT_01`, `FR_PLT_02` and so on. This works.

Also for `FR_Country*`, for pages `FR_Country_01`, `FR_Country_02` and so on. Works fine.

But if we want to combine, so `FR_PLT*|FR_Country*`, the report is empty.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this shortener version of your regular expression

```
FR_(PLT|Country)
```

And make sure you are using "regular expression" setting inside the filter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfectly valid regex that ought to do what you want, so here is my guess: are you opening the advanced filtration area and not switching the match type drop-down from Containing to Matching RegExp?

As a side note, that regex will match what you want, but I suspect not in the way you intend.
`FR_PLT*` matches pages containing `FR_PL` with or without `T` on the end, and `FR_Country*` matches pages containing `FR_Countr` with or without `y` on the end. In both cases the match is not case sensitive, so if you had a page under `fr_pl` it would also match the first regex.

To match `FR_PLT` with anything after it, you'd use the dot wildcard character:
`FR_PLT.*`. However, since regex matches **within** the string by default, rather than requiring a match on the entire string, you don't match any more or less with `FR_PLT.*` than with just `FR_PLT`.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing/confusing regular expressions with globs.   `FR_PLT*` would work as a glob, but not as a regular expression.   As a regular expression it would match:

- `FR_PL`
- `FR_PLT`
- `FR-PLTT`
- `FR-PLTTT`
- `ABC-FR-PLT-XYZ`
- etc.

because the star means "zero or more of the last character" and this regular expression appears to be applied in a "find" manner.  That means that the match just has to be *contained* in the string.  The equivalent regular expression you actually want is: `^FR_PLT.*` where `^` means "starts with" and `.*` means "zero or more of any characters." In regular expressions the `.` is the wildcard for "any character", as opposed to globs that use `*` to mean "any of any character."

Combining your two cases into a valid regular expression could be either of the following:

- `(^FR_PLT.*)|(^FR_Country.*)`
- `^FR_(PLT|Country).*`
- `^FR_(PLT|Country)`

They all mean exactly the same thing but the second one is simplified.   The `|` is "or" and the parenthesis are for grouping.  The last one omits the `.*` because the regular expression doesn't have to match the whole thing, it appears to be used in a "contains" context here.